# Opening a URL in a new tab

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an url like

```
Response.Redirect("~/webpages/frmCrystalReportViewer.aspx?VoucherNo=" + txtVoucherNo.Text + "&VoucherDate=" + txtVoucherDate.Text + " &strUserCode=" + strUserCode.ToString() + "&strCompanyCode=" + strCompanyCode.ToString() + "&formName=frmPaymentVoucher");
```

I want to open this url in new tab of browser.
I tried below code...

```
string pageurl = "~/webpages/frmCrystalReportViewer.aspx?VoucherNo=" + txtVoucherNo.Text + "&VoucherDate=" + txtVoucherDate.Text + " &strUserCode=" + strUserCode.ToString() + "&strCompanyCode=" + strCompanyCode.ToString() + "&formName=frmPaymentVoucher";
Response.Write("<script>");
Response.Write("window.open('" + pageurl + "','_blank')");
Response.Write("</script>");
```

also i tried below

```
string pageurl = "~/webpages/frmCrystalReportViewer.aspx?VoucherNo=" + txtVoucherNo.Text + "&VoucherDate=" + txtVoucherDate.Text + " &strUserCode=" + strUserCode.ToString() + "&strCompanyCode=" + strCompanyCode.ToString() + "&formName=frmPaymentVoucher";
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "popup", "window.open('" + pageurl + "','_blank')", true);
```

also i tried

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPrint" Text="Print" runat="server" OnClick="btnPrint_Click" OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';"/>
```

but all are not working.
Please tell me any another solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using URL with **~** and it won't recognize by javascript. You should process url with **~** by using **ResolveUrl** method which

> converts a URL into one that is usable on the requesting client(c)msdn

In your case:

```
Response.Write(String.Format("window.open('{0}','_blank')", ResolveUrl(pageurl)));
```

Comment: Or just remove the tilde to be relative to the app root.

Answer (score 5):

With the help of JavaScript we can set the target property of form to _blank whenever we want to open the page in a new window. Try the following

I have an ASP.Net Button

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="PRINT BILL" Onclick="btnPrint_Click"  OnClientClick="SetTarget();" />
```

I am calling the SetTarget() JavaScript function OnClientClick event of the ASP.Net Button Control as described below

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
 function SetTarget() {
     document.forms[0].target = "_blank";
 }
</script>
```

calling the btnPrint_Click method OnClick event Control as described below

```
 protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Response.Redirect("ReportViewer1.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: There is a problem with this. After the Javascript runs, any interaction with any control on the form (not just the button) will cause a new tab to be opened.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by anand360 worked for me. Thanks!!

I made a slight change in JavaScript as follows to access only the desired element.

```
document.getElementById["element_id"].target = "_blank";
```