# How to open a link in new tab using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am working on a website, in which I have to open a url from backend. I am using c# now. My problem is that I want to open link in new tab instead of new window.

My code is here:-

```
string url = ppHref.ToString();

string newScript = "<script language='javascript'>window.open('" + ppHref.ToString() + "', '_blank');</script>";

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"OpenUrl", newScript);
```

Can Anybody tell me how to open this url in new tab. I don't like pop ups so I don't wanna use `window.open()`. Please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Here you go:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896284/opening-a-url-in-a-new-tab

Comment: You need to set pop up property for the browser

Comment: @Rasher My code is working fine.But i want to open it into new tab, Not in new window

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1902352.aspx?How+to+open+a+page+in+new+tab+in+javascript+or+jquery+ This can be useful

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open a URL in a new tab using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.co.in');" target="_blank">Sample Code</a>
```

Comment: This works for me, but open one extra blank tab, just need to return false at the end of onclick event.

Comment: Chrome is blocking a popup when I'm trying this

Comment: @Valentin You need to allow the pop-up blocker in chrome browser settings

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
window.open(url,'_target')
```

`_target` opens the page in next tab.

Comment: this gets blocked by pop-up blockers

Answer (score 2):

Html Code :

```
<button onclick="OpenInNewTab();" type="submit">
```

Javascript Code :

```
function OpenInNewTab(url) {
    var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
    win.focus();
}
```

Change Your Browser Setting.

In **FireFox** ,

Go To **Options** -> **Tab** setting and **Check** "**Open New Windows in a New Tab instead**" setting.

*This Solution Worked For me .*

Answer (score 0):

I think answer to this question will help , Open a URL in a new tab using JavaScript https://stackoverflow.com/a/30512485/2293686

try like this,

```
$('#myButton').click(function () {
    var redirectWindow = window.open('url', '_blank');
    redirectWindow.location;
});
```