# How to open a link in new tab using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, browser-tab

I want to open a `url` in new tab.

I am using following code to open url in new tab.

```
var url = "/Billing/DownloadEDIForMultipleClaim?month=" + month + "&BillRequestIds=" + billRequestIds.join(',') + "&PatientIDs=" + patientIds.join(',');
window.open(url, '_blank'); //exception here
```

But this is not working for me it through an exception `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined`

I also used following.

```
var url = "/Billing/DownloadEDIForMultipleClaim?month=" + month + "&BillRequestIds=" + billRequestIds.join(',') + "&PatientIDs=" + patientIds.join(',');
var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
if(win) {
    //Browser has allowed it to be opened
    win.focus();
} else {
    //Broswer has blocked it
    alert('Please allow popups for this site');
}
```

I already seen related questions.

[How to open a URL in a new Tab using javascript or jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851782/how-to-open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript-or-jquery)

[How to open a link in new tab using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101713/how-to-open-a-link-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

But this is not working for me.

Comment: So basically what the message is saying is that `window` is undefined, which seems highly unlikely ?

Comment: `open is undefined' when I use 'window.location.href' then exception occur `location is undefined`

Comment: In the standard implementation of javascript inside a browser the window object should be defined to the current view surface. So you might have an browser issue or your code might have overloaded this object.

Comment: @DanielPersson I doubt about overloaded `window` object since that would not give this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined`.

Comment: Ok overloaded was the wrong wording :). Changed, overwritten or not defined.

Comment: @DanielPersson the global window object is read-only. Of course, one could define a local window variable, and that's probably what the issue is, something like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/jwzaydrL/**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sc3ownLp/ Check this out. You will need to unblock the pop-up.

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath - That's not the same error message, you've just mispelled `Open` !

Comment: @adeneo yeah, I forgot to fix that. It works now.

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath - well, yeah! `window.open` works for everyone, just not the OP apparantly, and showing that it works in a fiddle doesn't really help the OP at all?

Comment: @adeneo That is exactly why I indicated to the pop up. I do not see anyone has mentioned about this. Unless you allow the pop-up, it will not work and that could very well be the case. That is why, it clearly says you will need to unblock the pop-up.

Comment: What browser are you using? Is there other code around it? Show the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

This may be of use:
http://jsfiddle.net/vraCM/12/
it seems that this code snippet contains what you need for this to work.

```
$(function() {
   $("a[href^='http']:not([href*='jsfiddle.net'])").each(function() {
       $(this).click(function(event) {
             event.preventDefault();
             event.stopPropagation();
             window.open(this.href, '_blank');
        }).addClass('externalLink');
   });
});
```

The js fiddle contains code that can be manipulated to fit your parameters regarding pop-ups within an alert or new window etc.

Also, this article may be worth a read. http://www.jqueryfaqs.com/Articles/Open-new-tab-in-browser-using-jQuery.aspx