# How to remove target='_blank' after postback event?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, response.redirect

I have added a button on my asp page and I am executing some process at server side then redirecting a link to another page.

What I am doing in my page is that I am calling a method On `asp:Button` `OnClientClick` event where I am assigning a `aspnetForm.target='_blank'` to navigate the page in different tab.

**ASP.NET CODE:**

```
<asp:Button ID='btn' runtat='server' OnClientClick='ShowPage();' Text='Show Page' />
```

**JavaScript CODE:**

```
function ShowPage() {
    aspnetForm.target = '_blank';
}
```

I am using using `Response.Redirect()` method to navigate a page. This method is called only after verifying required validations at server side.

**C#.NET Code**

```
If (ValidData())
{
   Response.Redirect('myPage.aspx?preview=true', True);
}
```

The validation code is huge and there are also some further process are being executed during the validation. So, I cannot use `WebMethod` for `ajax` call.

Everything is working correctly but, the problem is that there are some other links and buttons also. So, when i click on any of them the page is also redirecting for that particular request and I don't want to do that. It happens because the `aspnetForm.target='_blank`` is still exist in the asp form and it will perform same action for other links also.

My requirement is that the page should be navigated in new tab only when a particular button is pressed. other navigation process should be done is same page. I am wondering that is there any method that i can use to remove `target = '_blank'` after postback.

I cannot use `rel='external'` because I am not using `anchor<a>` tag. I am using `asp:Button` which is also handling some server side events.

Or is there any other way that i can use to navigate the page in new tab without using `target='_blank'` method?

**EDITED:**

Currently I am using `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()` to execute my `Popup` window script. But, when the popup blocker is on it doesn't work. So, I have to chose another way.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "OpenWindow", "window.open('myPage.aspx?preview=true','_newtab');", True)
```

Comment: The one's you want to navigate to new tab put `target="_blank"` on them and don't put target at all on one's you want to navigate in same parent page. Is that makes sense or did i missed something magical here??

Comment: yes, your logic will work but, it would be painful to handle all controls' `OnClientClick` event when there are so much links and buttons placed in the page.

Comment: ah, `window.open()` would be painful as it behaves weirdly sometimes. Yes you are right it won't be easy because browsers open pages in new tabs if the request comes from a trusted source, if we try to do it manually then i don't think it will work as expected throughout. However you can try `window.open(url, '_blank')` or check [this link.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101713/how-to-open-a-link-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

Comment: Yes, I have also tried that and `_newtab` as well but it shows same popup blocker message.  I am redirecting page from server side and I am using `asp:Button` to trigger it. So, I cannot give the target tag to my element as suggested in accepted answer. I have also tried ajax call with `async: false`. but, still it shows same message.

Comment: After post back instead of removing `target=_blank` why don't you try to set it to another value like `target=_self`

Comment: @ShoaibShakeel I don't know where should I put that code to set the `target=_self` after postback. I am setting `target=_blank` in `OnClientClick` event of `asp:Button`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solve my issue by using `setTimeout()` method. I am resetting form attribute `target` to `_self` after `1000` milliseconds.

**Javascript Code:**

```
function ShowPage() {
    aspnetForm.target = "_blank";
    setTimeout(function() {
        aspnetForm.target = "_self";
    }, 1000);
}
```

**ASP.NET Code**

```
<asp:Button ID='btn' runtat='server' OnClientClick='ShowPage();' Text='Show Page' />
```

And, I can use my existing method `Response.Redirect()` which will not trigger the `Popup Blocker` message.

It will reset the `target` attribute of `form` to `_self` after navigating new tab.

Comment: Perfect answer! I've seen a lot of answers that do not work. You are brilliant!