# Redirect to new tab in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, response, response.redirect

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnPrint" runat="server" OnClick="lnkBtnPrint_OnClick" Target="_blank">
                    </asp:LinkButton>
```

I have Button. I need to open new tab with content on click.

```
 protected void lnkBtnPrint_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hdnSubmissionID.Value))
        {
            SessionHelper.Set(SessionKey.SubmissionId, hdnSubmissionID.Value);
            Response.Redirect(PublisherConfigurationManager.Navigation + "Printable_Submission_Document.aspx");
        }
    }
```

I try to apply answer from this post [Opening a URL in a new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896284/opening-a-url-in-a-new-tab) to my case, but just get text in top-left corner like 'window.open...'.

Add `_blank` to link - also doesn't help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dynamically redirecting based on a triggered click.  I think for this scenario, you could actually change it to set your HRef BEFORE the click, since you know your data on page load, provided that your sample code is complete.

```
public void Page_Load()
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hdnSubmissionID.Value))
    {
        SessionHelper.Set(SessionKey.SubmissionId, hdnSubmissionID.Value);
        lnkBtnPrint.HRef = PublisherConfigurationManager.Navigation + "Printable_Submission_Document.aspx");
    }
}
```

Keep your target set the way it is and remove the onclick event from your link button.  It should now open your "dynamic" target in a new window.

Comment: yes this helps. And can you suggest solution for case when in `lnkBtnPrint_OnClick` i check some variable (for example bool) and if true, then just simple redirect and if false, then open in new tab?

Comment: Are you able to check this variable on page load?  If so, I'd modify your lnkBtnPrint at that point in time to either have a Target="_blanK" or not.  If this isn't possible, you'll need some javascript to handle your case.

Comment: I likely don't understand something about how LinkButton works, but what good is setting HRef after the client-side click has already happened? The code that you showed is expected to run on the postback caused by the user clicking on the "a" element rendered by the LinkButton, correct?

Comment: @Igor My followup comment wouldn't use the code in my answer.  They are two different scenarios depending on what is needed.  In the first, you set the HRef up front.  In the second, you'd need to do something with the click event to obtain the target and url, then set them on the client and most likely call a hidden link instead that had been populated by the javascript.