# How to open page in new tab from GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, linkbutton

I want to open page in new tab while clicking on the gridview link button. But I want to open new page based on alert type. For example, from the given below grid I clicked link button of Alert1 then it should open **`alert1.aspx`** page, if it is Alert2 then **`alert2.aspx`**. etc
Help me to find a proper solution. Thank you.

**GridView:**

[image]

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeader="False"> 
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Alert Type" SortExpression="Alert_Type">
    <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Alert_Type") %>'>
    </asp:Label>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Alert_Type") %>'>
    </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Created_Time" HeaderText="Created Time" 
    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Created_Time" />
    <asp:TemplateField >
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk" runat="server" Text="Click" OnClick="lnk_Click">
    </asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>                
 </asp:GridView>
```

**C#:**

```
protected void lnk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenWindow", "window.open('alert1.aspx','_newtab');", true);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening a URL in a new tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896284/opening-a-url-in-a-new-tab)

Comment: you should be replace '_newtab' with '_blank'

Comment: You need to use NamingContainer in lnk_Click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution that you looking for:

```
 protected void lnk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      LinkButton lnk = sender as LinkButton;
      Label Label1 = lnk.NamingContainer.FindControl("Label1") as Label;

      if (Label1.Text == "Alert1")
      {
          Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenWindow", "window.open('alert1.aspx','_blank');", true);
      }
      else if (Label1.Text == "Alert2")
      {
          Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenWindow", "window.open('alert2.aspx','_blank');", true);
      }
 }
```

**Also, Give unique names to controls inside GridView.**

Answer (score 0):

Replace `'_newtab'` to `'_blank'`

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenWindow", "window.open('alert1.aspx','_blank');", true);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to set `target` attribute to `_blank`

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenWindow", "window.open('alert1.aspx','_blank');", true);
```

The second argument in `window.open` is to specify whether you want to open page in new tab or in existing tab. So you need to set it to `_blank` to open page in new tab

Comment: Hai Mairaj Ahmad, I need to open page in new tab, but I have one condition, If I click link button corresponding to Alert1 it should open alert1.aspx, or if If I click link button corresponding to Alert2 then open alert2.aspx page.

Answer (score -1):

set CommandName to alert type and access it  in click event

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk" runat="server" Text="Click" OnClick="lnk_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("Alert_Type") %>'>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Click event

```
protected void lnk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string alerttype=e.CommandArgument.ToString();
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenWindow", "window.open("+alerttype+"'.aspx','_newtab');", true);
}
```