# How to open page in new tab using the response. redirect at asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to open a new tab or a new page by using `Response.Redirect` in a button click handler. I'm using a query string to pass some values. How can I open he page in a new tab?

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...//some code to insert records
    Response.Redirect("NewQuote.aspx?val=" + this.txtQuotationNo.Text);//displaying gridview in other page to print what needed
}
```

Comment: this code is working , but opening in same page. i need to open in new tab

Comment: Look into LinkButtons and target="_blank"

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896284/opening-a-url-in-a-new-tab

Answer (score 23):

Try this. This works sure for me...

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...//some code to insert records
    Response.Write("<script>window.open ('NewQuote.aspx?val=" + txtQuotationNo.Text+"','_blank');</script>");
}
```

Comment: This will not open, unless the user has accepted popups from the site, which most will not.

Answer (score 18):

Simple solution is here.

Edit your html button element and add attribute *OnClientClick="target ='_blank';"*.

```
<asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn1"
            OnClick="btnSave_Click" OnClientClick="target ='_blank';" />
```

Then in btnSave_Click

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

Comment: did not work for me, and I wasn't sure I was expecting it to.  But I was hoping it would!

Comment: It did work for me.  @fufu can you explain why this works, I have to admit I didn't really think it would either.

Comment: @RickRunowski the target=_blank is used in hyperlinks in HTML, and it works the same when called from an ASP.NET object.

Comment: Just adding: OnClientClick="target ='_blank';"  to my existing image buttom worked for me, with my existing markup & code.  Thanks :)

Comment: This worked smoothly for me, while I was trying to open a pdf on click from byte stream :)

Answer (score 6):

You can change your design element as below : `OnClientClick`

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button"  OnClientClick ="document.forms[0].target = '_blank';"  />
```

Javascript code :

```
 Response.Write("<script>");
 Response.Write("window.open('NewQuote.aspx' ,'_blank')");
 Response.Write("</script>");
```

Comment: i have some code that has to be run in code behind event. at last of that event  i have to redirect. but i think as ur answer java script code will execute first than code behind.

Comment: @krishnamohan just have a look into javascript code

Comment: okok i will try ur code...but i have to pass some variable with NewQuote.aspx?val=

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this same problem today.

Response.write didn't work for me, to solve it I used instead System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock.

This is how your btnSave click event should be:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...//some code to insert records
    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "openModal", "window.open('NewQuote.aspx?val= "+ this.txtQuotationNo.Text+"' ,'_blank');", true);
}
```

NOTE: I'm using ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock because the button is inside an UpdatePanel, if that's not your case you should try:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...//some code to insert records
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "openModal", "window.open('NewQuote.aspx?val= " + this.txtQuotationNo.Text + "' ,'_blank');", true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using http
then use below code

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open ('URL','_blank');</script>");
```

this code cannot be used for https
for https do below

javascript in page

```
function shwwindow(myurl) {
    window.open(myurl, '_blank');
}
```

in c# code behind

```
 string URL = ResolveClientUrl("~") + "**internal page path**";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "show window", 
    "shwwindow('"+URL+"');", true);
```

this code cannot bybass the browser popup blocker. user must allow it to run.
for ie it opens in new window or new tab up to ie version
in firefox and chrome it opens new tab

enjoy it!!

Answer (score 1):

A redirect is always in the same page as where you came from, you can't open a new window from a redirect call.

I would suggest to inject some javascript code in the client to open the new page on reload, or change to a control that can open to a new page, like a `LinkButton` with the right `Target` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ScriptManager to do the needed:

```
private void Redirect_New_Tab(string url_To_Open)
{    
    string modified_URL = "window.open('" + url_To_Open + "', '_blank');";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", modified_URL , true);
}
```

Comment: A bit more context would be helpful, not only plain code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me when I left the Double Quotes off of target ='_blank';

Answer (score 0):

Response.write didn't work for me, so I used instead System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock.

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "openModal", "window.open('NewQuote.aspx?val= "+ this.txtQuotationNo.Text+"' ,'_blank');", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent quite some time on this, and while it does work to set the target on the form to _blank it will mean that every other control on that page will attempt to open in a new window afterwards. And you can't manipulate the form back server side, since the response will never reach the orginal tab.

So I made it work with a combination of setting the target to _blank when the button is clicked, and then shortly after reset the target back.

I put in this Javascript function on the page:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function openInNewTab() {
        document.forms[0].target = "_blank";
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.forms[0].removeAttribute('target'); // After 500 ms revert back to normal mode so all other controls are not affected.
        }, 500);
    }
```

And on the control that needs to open in a new tab just add:

```
OnClientClick="openInNewTab();"
```