# How to open link in a new tab ('target=_blank') on form submit in VB?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a ASP/VB control that produces a basic form with two inputs. On form submit I want to open the action URL in a new tab instead of the parent.

One of our original developers put some code in place that (I assume) should accomplish this, but there must be a mistake in the code as it doesn't work. This code is referenced below.

In the ASCX file:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnZipCodeSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" />
<asp:literal id="litLink" runat="server"></asp:literal>
```

In the corresponding VB File:

```
Protected Sub btnZipCodeSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnZipCodeSearch.Click
        Search()
        Response.Redirect("https://www.mylink.com?z=" & txtZipCode.Text & ")
        litLink.text = "<a href='" & "https://www.mylink.com?z=" & txtZipCode.Text & "' target='_blank'>Link</a>"
End Sub
```

The expected result is when the 'search' button is clicked the action URL (search results) will open in a new tab.

Comment: Isn't that `Reponse.Redirect` going to send the users to www.mylink, which the makes the link that's bound to litLink.text moot? Also, the URL in the Response.Redirect is missing ".com".

Comment: If those comments weren't a help, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38392553/2654498).

Comment: `form target="_blank"`

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer in the related post that Nicholas V commented, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38392553/2654498). Ironically, it was the one answer I didn't expect to work, it was just too simple (and it was meant for C#, not VB).

The result was that I appended `OnClientClick="target ='_blank'"` to the asp button, used my existing `Response.Redirect` code and commentented out the `litLink.text` code.