# How to create a text file from a string and open it in new tab in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to create a text file from a string and send it to browser's new tab on a button click in aspx page. The file must be created on the fly and should not be stored anywhere on server.

Currently, I am able to send the file on the same tab by attaching the file in the http response and sending that response to browser.

Comment: Hum, any particular reason you don't just create a string and pass it on to the next page for display? It is not at all clear why a text file is being used, or even required here since as you note, you have zero interest in creating a text file anyway. So, why have or create or use or even consider a text file for such a goal?

Comment: You can use binary data without needs for a file. In a global variable you can store that data then you can send that data to the browser with  
    `Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & fileName)
                            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf" '& extension.Replace(".", "")

                            Dim dati As Byte() = Yourdata here
                            Response.BinaryWrite(dati)
                            Response.Flush()` Work on this

Comment: You will find some solution below this topic. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510275/how-to-open-page-in-new-tab-using-the-response-redirect-at-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

unfortantly, due to popup blockers, creating a tab really not going to work these days.

However, you can on the same page, say a button click, and then "fake" the same thing as if the user did navigate to a simple text document.

This code will work:

```
Protected Sub cmdJump_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim strBuf =
        "First line of text" & vbCrLf &
        "Seond line of text" & vbCrLf &
        "Third line of text"

    Dim strFakeFileName As String = "mytext.txt"
    Dim strConType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(strFakeFileName)

    Response.Clear()
    Response.ContentType = strConType
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", strBuf.Length)
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" & strFakeFileName)
    Response.Write(strBuf)
    Response.End()

End Sub
```

As noted, this will occur on the current page. User can hit back button.

However, opening a new tab? Modern browsers just don't allow this with much success.