# OnClientClick=_blank of button one affecting OnClick of button two

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have two buttons. One for previewing CSS changes on a website and the other to save the changes. When I click the preview button it creates a temp css file and then redirects to a website in a new tab. If I go back to the original tab and click save it goes to the new website tab and does the save on that page and reloads as tab one. So I have two tabs that are same the page. How do I force the save to happen on the first tab and not happen on the second tab? Also if I click save before I preview it works as intended and happens in the same tab

One thing that makes this unique is that the buttons are created dynamically from the code behind

```
            Button btnSubmit = new Button();
            btnSubmit.Click += new EventHandler(btnSubmit_Click);
            btnSubmit.CssClass = "layoutSettings_saveButton";
            btnSubmit.Text = "Save";
            btnSubmit.ID = "btnSubmit" + CatCount;
            divPanelBody.Controls.Add(btnSubmit);

            Button btnPreview = new Button();
            btnPreview.Click += new EventHandler(btnPreview_Click);
            btnPreview.CssClass = "layoutSettings_previewButton";
            btnPreview.ID = "btnPreview" + CatCount;
            btnPreview.Text = "Preview";
            btnPreview.OnClientClick += "target ='_blank';";
            divPanelBody.Controls.Add(btnPreview);
```

```
btnPreview_Click Does the redirect to the website
```

```
        string navURL = "http://" + url + "/?preview=1";
        Response.Redirect(navURL);
```

No Redirects for the btnSubmit_Click it just saves data and displays a message.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576169/is-it-possible-to-add-2-response-redirect-one-will-open-in-different-tab-and-ot window.open('../User/Profile.html', 'tabName');
window.location.href = '../User/NewUser.aspx';

Comment: use some javascript library, to open an iframe dialog inside your page - there you can control what you show.