# Windows desktop application open URL in a new browser window instead of a new tab

Tags: c#

I am using `Process.Start(url)` to open a url in a new tab in user's browser. However, I want it to be opened in a new browser window instead of a new tab. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening a URL in a new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896284/opening-a-url-in-a-new-tab)

Comment: Is this from an ASP.NET context, or a desktop application? If the former, it isn't going to work.

Comment: This is a desktop application.

Comment: This is different from creating a response. I wish to let the desktop application visit the url in a new browser window.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the overloaded [`Process.Start(string, string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx) which will take command line arguments. [Firefox](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments) and [Chrome](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) both have a command line switch to specify a new window. You'll need to figure out what Browser the client has, and use the appropriate command line args.

Comment: I tried it. If I have my chrome browser running, it will still open this url in a new tab instead of a new window.

Comment: [I've verified that --new-window does work](https://shifty.site/lKz5t). Can you update your main post with how you're calling `Process.Start`?